# strncmp gives 0 even when strings are NOT equal - C

Tags: c, fgets, c-strings, strcmp, strncmp

I am having a situation with `strncmp` function in C, it is returning 0 even when the words do not match, in the example below, I am testing it with the letter 'R' and when running the code it returns 0 even when the compared word in the txt document is 'RUN'. Do you happen to know whether

Am I missing something in the strncmp function or somewhere else in my code?

Thank you for your input.

---

```c
bool lookup(string s);

int main(void) {

char *s;
s = "R";
if (lookup(s)) {
    printf("Word found =)\n");
} else {
    printf("Word not found =(\n");
}
}

// Looks up word, s, in txt document.
bool lookup(string s)
{
 // TODO
    char *wordtosearch;
    wordtosearch = s;
    int lenwordtosearch = strlen(wordtosearch);
    char arraywordindic[50];

// Open txt file
FILE *file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
if (file == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot open file, please try again...\n");
    return false;
}

while (!feof(file)) {
    if (fgets(arraywordindic, 50, file) != NULL) {
        char *wordindic;
        wordindic = arraywordindic;
        int result = strncmp(wordindic, wordtosearch, lenwordtosearch);
        if (result == 0) {
            printf("%i\n", result);
            printf("%s\n", wordindic);
            printf("%s\n", wordtosearch);
            fclose(file);
            return true;
        }
    }        
}
fclose(file);
return false;
}
```

Comment: `strncmp` compares only first `lenwordtosearch` (the third argument) characters and returns 0 iff they matches, so your code seems working well. What is your expected behavior?

Comment: By the way, C don't have standard `string` type. Are you using `cs50.h`?

Comment: Hi MikeCAT, yes cs50.h. The thing is that it compares R with RUN and it gives 0. I want it to return 0 when it finds R only.

Comment: read [why while( feof() ) is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: regarding: `while (!feof(file)) {
    if (fgets(arraywordindic, 50, file) != NULL) {`  suggest combining into a single statement: `while ( fgets(arraywordindic, 50, file) ) {`

Comment: OT: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 50.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest: use a `enum` statement or `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name.  Then use the meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Cannot open file, please try again...\n");`  This is just telling the user that some error occurred, not why it occurred.  Also error messages should be output to `stderr` and when the error is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system, thinks the error occurred.  Suggest: `perror( "fopen failed" );`  as that will output both the error message and the text reason to `stderr`.

Comment: regarding: `if (fgets(arraywordindic, 50, file) != NULL) {`  This will also input the trailing newline `'\n'` which will ruin any string comparison.  Suggest the next statement be: `arraywordindic[ strcspn( arraywordindic, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding; `int lenwordtosearch = strlen(wordtosearch);`  The function: `strlen()` returns a type `size_t` which is a `unsigned long int`  The result is trying to push a unsigned value into a signed value.  This should be avoided

Comment: this function: `int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);`  expects the third parameter to have type `size_t`, so `lenwordtosearch` needs to have type `size_t`, not `int`

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable input. Will make adjustments as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing is that it compares R with RUN and it gives 0. I want it to
> return 0 when it finds R only.

In this case you need to compare whole words using the function `strcmp` instead of comparing only `lenwordtosearch` characters using the function `strncmp`.

Take into account that the function `fgets` can append the new line character `'\n'` to the entered string. You need to remove it before comparing strings.

```
if (fgets(arraywordindic, 50, file) != NULL) {
    arraywordindic[ strcspn( arraywordindic, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
    int result = strcmp(arraywordindic, wordtosearch);
    if (result == 0) {
        printf("%i\n", result);
        printf("%s\n", arraywordindic);
        printf("%s\n", wordtosearch);
```

As a result these declarations

```
int lenwordtosearch = strlen(wordtosearch);
```

and

```
char *wordindic;
wordindic = arraywordindic
```

may be removed.

And the condition of the while loop should be written like

```
while ( fgets(arraywordindic, 50, file) != NULL ) {
    arraywordindic[ strcspn( arraywordindic, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
    int result = strcmp(arraywordindic, wordtosearch);
    if (result == 0) {
        printf("%i\n", result);
        printf("%s\n", arraywordindic);
        printf("%s\n", wordtosearch);
    //...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int result = strncmp(wordindic, wordtosearch, lenwordtosearch);
```

This is going to give you zero if the first `lenwordtosearch` characters of `wordtosearch` matches the first `lenwordtosearch` characters of any word in the dictionary.

Given that the word you're searching for is `S`, any word in the dictioanary that *starts* with `S` is going to give you a match.

You should probably be checking the *entire* word. That probably means cleaning up the word you've read in from the file (i.e., removing newline) and using `strcmp()` instead, something like:

```
wordindic = arraywordindic;

// Add this:
size_t sz = strlen(wordindic);
if (sz > 0 && wordindic[sz - 1] == '\n')
    wordindic[sz - 1] = '\0';

// Modify this:
// int result = strncmp(wordindic, wordtosearch, lenwordtosearch);
int result = strcmp(wordindic, wordtosearch);
```

Comment: Hello paxdiablo, thank you, I edited the post as I made a typo. The example test letter I am using is R and let´s say the word in the text document is RUN, R and RUN are not the same, hence strncmp should give 0, unless there is an R only in the text document. At least that is how I understand strncmp works.

As per tutorialspoint.com: "The C library function int strncmp(const char *str1, const char *str2, size_t n) compares at most the first n bytes of str1 and str2."

Comment: @Logan, if you're using the length of `"R"` to compare the two strings (and you are), you'll get a match on every word starting with `R`. `R` and `RUN` may be different but you're comparing `R` against the ***first letter*** of `RUN`. So, yes, your understanding of `strncmp()` is wrong :-)

Comment: A useful idea: When overwriting the `'\n'`, decrement the `sz`.  Then it remains a useful length for later code.  `wordindic[sz - 1] = '\0';` --> `wordindic[--sz] = '\0';`

Comment: Thank you @paxdiablo